# Mocked function not returning expected value

Tags: c#, vb.net, unit-testing, moq

I have a static method

```
Public Shared Function UpdateGroup(ByVal details As GroupDetails)
    As ControllerResult
    Return _methodObject.UpdateGroup(details)
End Function
```

that was refactored to be able to mock with help of

```
Private Shared _methodObject As ISecurityController = 
     New SecurityControllerMethodObject()

Public Shared Sub OverrideInstance(ByVal controller As ISecurityController)
    _methodObject = controller
End Sub
```

Then on my test I have

```
var moqSecurityController = new Mock<ISecurityController>();
    moqSecurityController
        .Setup(x => x.UpdateGroup(groupDetails))
        .Returns(controllerResult);

SecurityController.OverrideInstance(moqSecurityController.Object);
```

If I put a breakpoint on that last line I can see that groupDetails have what it should as well as controllerResult, so I would expect that when Function UpdateGroup is called, the controllerResult would be returned, which is just a simple class with a Message & Success properties.

However, what I get is Null/Nothing.

What am I missing?

Note: As you might have noticed, the production code is in VB.NET, my tests are in C#.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is it because your groupDetails don't match?

try

```
var moqSecurityController = new Mock<ISecurityController>();
moqSecurityController.Setup(
  x => x.UpdateGroup(It.IsAny<GroupDetails>())
).Returns(controllerResult);
```